# Floating button that follows scroll but returns back to it's home (HTML, C#.NET)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, .net

This seems like a simple task but I've found it to be a challenge.  At least for it to work with most browsers.  The easy way is to simply set a css property on the button so that it always stays fixed on the bottom.  The problem with this is for applications where the button was originally in a certain location within all the other buttons, it will now always be at the bottom.  You can achieve this by wrapping a  tag around the button like so.

```html
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;">
Some html button
</div>
```

So the other way I found was using IntersectionObserver API within Javascript.  This seems to be the most modern way.  I detect the scroll, and when the element disappears I enable a hidden button.  It works pefectly in Chrome, but dosen't in IE since IntersectionObserver is not supported in IE.

```js
            var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries) {
                if (entries[0].isIntersecting === true) {
                    console.log('Element is here')
                    document.getElementById("floating_button").style.cssText = "display: none";
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Element is gone')
                    document.getElementById("floating_button").style.cssText = "position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;";
                }
            }, { threshold: [0] });

            observer.observe(document.querySelector("#scroll_button"));
```

So I'm at a loss on which way to do this.  There are ways of doing this with traditional Jquery, Javacript, but the one's I'm finding don't seem to work and using "sticky" for divs are not supported in IE either.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following either from stack overflow or another source.  This seems to work on all browsers.

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
            var elementTop = $('#some_span').offset().top;
            var elementBottom = elementTop + $('#some_span').outerHeight();
            var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

            var isinview = elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom

            if (isinview) {
                document.getElementById("some_floating").style.cssText = "display: none";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("some_floating").style.cssText = "position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;";
            }
        });
```